# 48,000 Photo Library Searchable Through Multiple, simultaneous Keywords

Tags: search, metadata, image, keyword

My assignment is to upload about 30K stock photo images to SharePoint 2013 for staff to narrow searches through the usage of multiple keywords. Images are tagged already.

Ideally I will have an extended checkbox list (multiple checks allowed to narrow search further) in lieu of staff typing in multiple keywords.

Screenshot attached of example tags used in Adobe Bridge.

[image: example of my goal used in Adobe Bridge]

I have viewed several tutorials on youtube but have yet to find one suitable to my needs.

Thoughts/help?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Managed metadata** is what handles *faceted navigation* requirements of this kind.

[image]

You can do this:

1. Export all unique tags from files (or directly from Adobe Bridge)
2. Import them all to MMS (powershell or Excel way)
3. Import files to SP doclib, setting tags for each one

But storing 48000 (probably-HiRes) images in SharePoint just *to navigate faster*? I hope you have offloading solution in place! Alternatively,

3. Put files to a shared location cheaper than SQL database (shared folder on NAS or fileserver). Create a custom list in SP, and for each image do create an item with URL to that file + tags

Finally,

4. Configure metadata navigation on the lib/list.

*Image from http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/managed-metadata-addendum-why-metadata.html*

Comment: I would use an Image Library or Asset Library rather than a Document library. They are designed for Image content types and handle reviews and renditions WAY better.